# padding with PKCS7 [C]

Tags: c, padding, pkcs#7

I want to do padding with PKCS7 :

```
char *test1 = "azertyuiopqsdfgh";
char *test2 = malloc(32*sizeof(char));

memcpy(test2, test1, strlen(test1));

char pad = (char)(32-strlen(test1));
printf("pad = %d\n", pad);

for(int i = strlen(test1) ; i < 32 ; i++) {
    test2[i] = pad;
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++)
    printf("%x ", test2[i]);
printf("\n");
```

I obtain :

```
pad = 16

61 7a 65 72 74 79 75 69 6f 70 71 73 64 66 67 68 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

But i want :

```
pad = 16

61 7a 65 72 74 79 75 69 6f 70 71 73 64 66 67 68 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
```

How can i modify my code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
printf("%x ", test2[i]);
```

You are printing in hexadecimal (**%x**) whereas with

```
printf("pad = %d\n", pad);` you are printing in decimal (%d).
```

And **(decimal) 16 => (hexa) 10**, So you are displaying the right thing.

You could probably play a bit with your printing to display 16 instead of 10 but I don't think this is what you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks. So, with PKCS7, i must complete with the decimal value 16 (= 10 (hexa)) and not the hexa value 16 (=22 (decimal)), right ?

Comment: @user1517752 Yes, exactly. the value of pad must represent the length (which ever base you use) of the padding. To me, you are doing it right!

Comment: @user1517752 be careful though with the use of strlen in cryptographic environments

Comment: Cryptography often use char arrays to represent integers. So if there is a 0 (which is \0 in ascii) in your ciphered data, it will be interpreted as the end of the string by strlen. For the same reason it is unsafe to print("%s",ciphered data).
But it was only a general advise, if i remember correctly pkcs7 padding comes in before encrypting.